# Printing a calendar

Tags: java, calendar

I know how to create normal calendar which would be something like this.

code:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class CalendarDateExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create an instance of a GregorianCalendar
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2014, 1, 06);

        System.out.println("Year: " + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        System.out.println("Month: " + (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1));
        System.out.println("Day: " + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        // Format the output.
        SimpleDateFormat date_format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        System.out.println(date_format.format(calendar.getTime()));
    }
}
```

Output :
    Year: 2014
    Month: 2
   Day: 6
   2014-02-06

But how would display a calender for given month and year making it look like:

```
July 2005
   S  M  T  W Th  F  S
                 1  2 
   3  4  5  6  7  8  9  
  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
  17 18 19 20 21 22 23 
  24 25 26 27 28 29 30 
  31
```

I am new to java , would like know how to do it the way above. any help would be great! 
thanks in advance

Comment: a java `Calendar` is not a representation of a month but some "tool" to work with dates. You will have to implement the full logic to get an output looking like `cal`'s one

Comment: Do you want to display this sort of a calendar in a console, on a webpage, in a desktop app? The `Calendar` class you're using is just meant for representing and converting time, not displaying it in a neat way. Depending on the app you're developing, there's probably a dozen libraries that can handle this piece of functionality.
Is your goal to develop a simple console app (judging by the code provided)?

Comment: @rc is it possible you could post a link or something like that which would be helpful to start on with this ?

Comment: @tom I would to make calendar in IDE just for something i am working on .

Comment: That's not the way it works, show us some effort, explain where you are stuck and you'll find help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2014, 1, 06);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); //Set the day of month to 1
int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); //get day of week for 1st of month
int daysInMonth = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

//print month name and year
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM YYYY").format(calendar.getTime()));
System.out.println(" S  M  T  W  T  F  S");

//print initial spaces
String initialSpace = "";
for (int i = 0; i < dayOfWeek - 1; i++) {
    initialSpace += "   ";
}
System.out.print(initialSpace);

//print the days of the month starting from 1
for (int i = 0, dayOfMonth = 1; dayOfMonth <= daysInMonth; i++) {
    for (int j = ((i == 0) ? dayOfWeek - 1 : 0); j < 7 && (dayOfMonth <= daysInMonth); j++) {
        System.out.printf("%2d ", dayOfMonth);
        dayOfMonth++;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

```
February 2014
 S  M  T  W  T  F  S
                   1 
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8 
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
16 17 18 19 20 21 22 
23 24 25 26 27 28
```

Comment: Thanks, I translated it to LocalDate. Your answer helped me