# Printing out a calendar in java

Tags: java, calendar, printf

```
public static String printMonth() {
    String[] months = {"", "January", "February", "March", 
            "April", "May", "June","July", "August", 
            "September", "October", "November", "December"};
    int[] days = {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 29};

    if((month == 2) && (leap = true)) {
        days[month] = 29;
    }

    System.out.println(months[month]);
    System.out.println( "Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa");

    if(day == 1)  {
        for (int i = 0; i < day; i++)
            System.out.print("   ");
        for (int i = 1; i <= days[month]; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%2d ", i);
            if (((i + day) % 7 == 0) || (i == days[month]))
                System.out.println();
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Output that I get:

```
January
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
    1  2  3  4  5  6 
 7  8  9 10 11 12 13 
14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 
28 29 30 31
```

Output I desire:

```
January
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
1  2  3  4  5  6  7
etc.
```

I am having trouble making the day of the month start on anything other than Monday. How do I go about making a month start on a Tuesday or any other day of the week? I have a scanner that takes in what day to start but am unsure of the print statement I should use.

Comment: It looks like a duplication of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26962388/printing-a-calendar)

Comment: Not really a dupe of that one since that is using `Calendar` (an outdated class that no one should use these days) whereas it seems that this user may be restricted to hand coding everything.

Comment: `(month == 2) && (leap = true)` is wrong. Can you figure out how and why? Just use `(month == 2) && leap`.