# Can anyone please tell what changes do I need to make in this code to display the calender in a tabular format?

Tags: java, calendar

Below is a sample code that is displaying info only until the month, and not the respective days of that month. Can someone help figure out the last loop that I need to put in order to make it run appropriately?

```java
public static void main(String a[])
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter the year");
    int yy = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("enter month");
    int mm = sc.nextInt();
    int d = 1;
    int m = 1;
    int y = 1;
    int dy = 1;
    String day[] = {"SUN", "MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT"}; //stores all 7 days of the week
    String month[] = {"JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", "OCTOBER", "NO VEMBER", "DECEMBER"}; //collection of all possible months of the year
    int ar[] = {31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    while (true) {
        if (d == 1 && m == mm && y == yy) {
            break;
        }
        if (y % 4 == 0 && y % 100 != 0 || y % 100 == 0) {
            ar[1] = 29; // if the year is a leap year then store 29
        } else {
            ar[1] = 28; //else 28
        }
        dy++;
        d++;
        if (d > ar[m - 1]) {
            m++;
            d = 1; //incrementing month count and re-initializing day as 1
        }
        if (m > 12) {
            m = 1;
            y++; // incrementing year count
        }
        if (dy == 7) {
            dy = 0; // if day count reachers 7, that is end of week, make it 0 again
        }
    }
    int c = dy;
    if (y % 4 == 0 && y % 100 != 0 || y % 400 == 0) {
        ar[1] = 29;
    } else {
        ar[1] = 28;
    }
    System.out.println("MONTH:" + month[mm - 1]); //print month
    for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++) {
        System.out.print(day[k] + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

Comment: I haven’t tried your code. Doesn’t it print in tabular form already? Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: It prints only the days sequentially but not the dates in proper format

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t get exactly what you mean by that. You may want to include in the question an example of how you had wanted it to look and how it looks instead. Format output as code to keep its format.

Comment: If the user enters the year 2000 and the month 11 (for November) then the output will display all the 30 days in a proper format as is visible in a calender.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26963197) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64054974/4725875) what you are trying to do?

Comment: @DevilsHnd Thanks